# How to avoid access to modified closure in linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq, closures

I have the following code:

```
ServiceSoapClient service = new ServiceSoapClient();
    var dataSource = (from u in _db.Sessions
                      where u.DeletedOn == null
                      select new
                      {
                          SessionId = u.UploadSessionId,
                          FileName = u.FileName,
                          CreatedBy = u.User.UserName,
                          Partner = u.Company.Name,
                          CreatedOn = u.CreatedOn,
                          Visible = service.IsSessionProcessing(u.UploadSessionId)
                      })
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn);
```

...of course the problem here is the `Visible = service.IsSessionProcessing(u.UploadSessionId)` portion that has access to modified closure because the expression is actually calculated when I use `dataSource` somewhere i.e preform `.ToList()` or something similar.

The problem here is that I can't perform `.ToList()` immediately because I need to use it as a data source for a control as it is.

Is there any way to avoid this in Linq? Can I use a local variable in the expression itself so that it gets calculated with the real values?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this `u` is *already* local to the expression... is something reporting that as a modified closure?

Comment: When I use the anonymous type collection that is returned... all the values from service.IsSessionProcessing(u.UploadSessionId) are equal to the last one...

Comment: well, I'm guessing that they are all either `true` or `false`, so not *many* options; however, are the `SessionId` different?

Comment: See... `u` isn't a closure, so neither `u` nor `u.UploadSessionId` can really be a modified closure. Now, depending on what your `_db.Sessions` is (and what plumbing is in the middle), it could be a bug somewhere there... but it doesn't feel related to modified closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "modified closure" here is `service`. So... don't reassign `service`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely. You're saying not to reassign it with new or not to call it in the linq expression?

Comment: @bojanskr what I'm saying is: `service` is ***the only closure*** here. So if you are genuinely seeing a "modified closure", that is the only candidate. More likely (IMO): the bug is not what/where you think it is.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I know where the bug is, and you were right, it's not in the closure at all, it's most probably in the service that i'm calling

Answer (score 0):

The real bug is in trying to call function in context of expression, which make no sence for an expression representing a database operation.
I suppose you actually tried the following:

```
// Database operation, no soap client funny business here.
 var list = (
  from u in _db.Sessions
  where u.DeletedOn == null
  orderby x.CreatedOn descending
  select new
  {
   SessionId = u.UploadSessionId,
   FileName = u.FileName,
   CreatedBy = u.User.UserName,
   Partner = u.Company.Name,
   CreatedOn = u.CreatedOn,
  }).ToList();

// From now on you are not in a database anymore, it's pure linq-to-objects. You can call the service.
ServiceSoapClient service = new ServiceSoapClient();
var dataSource = (from u in list select new {
 SessionId = u.SessionId,
 FileName = u.FileName,
 CreatedBy = u.CreatedBy,
 Partner = u.Partner,
 CreatedOn = u.CreatedOn,
 Visible = service.IsSessionProcessing(u.SessionId)
}).ToList();
```